# How to convert an emgu image to an XNA Texture2D?

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, xna, emgucv

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> video = cap.QueryFrame();
Texture2D t = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, video.Width, video.Height, false, SurfaceFormat.Color);
t.SetData<byte>(video.Bytes);
```

> ArgumentException was unhandled
>
> The size of the data passed in is too large or too small for this resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My perfered way is to 'save' the image into memory then load it with the `Texture2D.FromStream` function.

```
Texture2D t;

using(MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    Image<Bgr, Byte> video = cap.QueryFrame();
    cap.save(memStream, ImageFormat.PNG);
    t = Texture2D.FromStream(GraphicsDevice, memStream, video.Width, video.Height, 1f)
}
```

This will work with the NonPremultiplied BlendStates but if you want to use Premultiplied alpha you should run the Texture2D though the following function. This function simply uses the GPU to quickly premultiply the texture's alpha the same as the content processor would.

```
    static public void PreMultiplyAlpha(this Texture2D texture) {            

        //Setup a render target to hold our final texture which will have premulitplied color values
        var result = new RenderTarget2D(texture.GraphicsDevice, texture.Width, texture.Height);

        texture.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(result);
        texture.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

        // Using default blending function
        // (source × Blend.SourceAlpha) + (destination × Blend.InvSourceAlpha)
        // Destination is zero so the reduces to
        // (source × Blend.SourceAlpha)
        // So this multiplies our color values by the alpha value and draws it to the RenderTarget
        var blendColor = new BlendState {
            ColorWriteChannels = ColorWriteChannels.Red | ColorWriteChannels.Green | ColorWriteChannels.Blue,
            AlphaDestinationBlend = Blend.Zero,
            ColorDestinationBlend = Blend.Zero,
            AlphaSourceBlend = Blend.SourceAlpha,
            ColorSourceBlend = Blend.SourceAlpha
        };

        var spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(texture.GraphicsDevice);
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, blendColor);
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, texture.Bounds, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();

        // Simply copy over the alpha channel
        var blendAlpha = new BlendState {
            ColorWriteChannels = ColorWriteChannels.Alpha,
            AlphaDestinationBlend = Blend.Zero,
            ColorDestinationBlend = Blend.Zero,
            AlphaSourceBlend = Blend.One,
            ColorSourceBlend = Blend.One
        };

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, blendAlpha);
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, texture.Bounds, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();

        texture.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

        var t = new Color[result.Width * result.Height];
        result.GetData(t);
        texture.SetData(t);
    }
```

Comment: Are there any advantages to this method? better memory usage? speed?

Comment: Well if you want to use PreMultiplied Alpha (XNA does by default) then the GPU trick is necessary. PreMultiplied Alpha is a slight performance gain over non PreMultiplied Alpha. The advantage of the saving is that you don't have to worry about how the image is represented internally. Image can be absolutely any format and because you saving and loading as png so it abstracts away some complexity. Unless this is real time the performance issues are not worth considering. Same memory usage because you have to clone the byte array anyways because the color format is wrong.

Comment: I guess its also worth noting that png compression is lossless so there's no concern about loosing information.

Answer (score 0):

the video stores images in (Blue, green, Red) format. Whereas texture2d expects an extra alpha pixel as well.

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> video = cap.QueryFrame();
Image<Bgra, Byte> video2 = video.Convert<Bgra, Byte>();
Texture2D t = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, video.Width, video.Height, false, SurfaceFormat.Color);
t.SetData<byte>(video2.Bytes);
```